# How to run bat file stored in project from java?

Tags: java

I wonder if I can launch bat file stored under my project from java.

This my snippets of relevant code:

```
String[] input = new String[3];
input[0] = "cmd.exe";
input[1] = "/c";
input[2] = "data/run.bat";

Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p = r.exec(input);
```

Lets say my `run.bat` file is stored under `data` folder in project.

However I need provide full path to project that I try to avoid.

This is a actual output (with `System.out.println(Arrays.asList( input ) );`) what I get on launch:

```
[cmd.exe, /c, data/run.bat]
```

My expected output:

```
[cmd.exe, /c, C:/MyProject/data/run.bat]
```

Please, help,

Comment: what is 'input' ? please provide more code

Comment: Why did you expect that output?

Comment: you just print an array of strings, why do you expect it to be anything else?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to get the full path of the file. Right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
input[2] = new File("./data/run.bat").getAbsolutePath();
```

[Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html)

Comment: Dont forget the semicolin

Comment: Thanks, I've been doing most my code in non-semicolon languages.

Answer (score 0):

```
File file = new File("./data/run.bat");
input[2] = file.getAbsolutePath();
```